# Limit of a sequence = subsequence of a limit subsequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let there be a sequence $a_n$ and for all subsequence of it $b_n$ there is a subsequence $c_n$ that convergence to $a$
>   
>   Prove: $a_n \rightarrow a$

Where should I start?

Answer (score 3):

1. Suppose $a_n\not\to a$
2. Construct a subsequence of $a_n$ that has no subsequence with limit $a$. Can you do that?

Comment: the subsequence $b_n$ is monotonic but what next?

Comment: If it has no convergent subsequence, you have reached a contradiction.

Comment: shouldn't $b_n$ be bounded so it will have a  convergent subsequence?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant "no subsequence converges to $a$.